# bar button disappear on splitview controller when orientation change in ipad application

Tags: ipad

i use splitview controller in my ipad application, it works ok, but sometimes when i change interface from landscape to portrait it disappear bar button and popovercontroller from the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the "animated" parameter to NO in the setItems method of the toolbar.

```
- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController*)pc {

    barButtonItem.title = @"Clients";
    NSMutableArray *items = [[toolbar items] mutableCopy];
    [items insertObject:barButtonItem atIndex:0];
    [toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
    [items release];
    self.popoverController = pc;
}

- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {

    NSMutableArray *items = [[toolbar items] mutableCopy];
    [items removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
    [items release];
    self.popoverController = nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dude I was facing the same issue and after setting the toolbar animation to NO my problem got resolved. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

This was a known issue with some of the iPad SDK betas. Was this project created with a beta? If so I would create a new split view project with the GM release and then copy your existing code into the new split view project.

Comment: Interesting answer, but it really is a "superstition" solution.  What is the mechanism that makes the toolbar disappear?  Do apps have access to that mechanism or is it completely hidden?